# FTP server using python and twisted framework

Tags: python, macos, ftp, twisted

I want to create the ftp server in python which will fetch the file structure from my webserver using REST API and show in MAC OS's file system. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this task? I want to show file folder structure in OSX's file system which will be the mirror copy of files and folders structure on web server.
can anybody tell me how can I connect ftp server in python to my webserver ?

Below is some code which I found for get list and establish connection.

Can anybody suggest me how can I achieve my goal?

```
class DTP(object, protocol.Protocol):
    implements(interfaces.IConsumer)

    isConnected = False

    _cons = None
    _onConnLost = None
    _buffer = None

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.isConnected = True
        self.factory.deferred.callback(None)
        self._buffer = []

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.isConnected = False
        if self._onConnLost is not None:
            self._onConnLost.callback(None)

    def sendLine(self, line):
        self.transport.write(line + '\r\n')


    def _formatOneListResponse(self, name, size, directory, permissions, hardlinks, modified, owner, group):
        def formatMode(mode):
            return ''.join([mode & (256 >> n) and 'rwx'[n % 3] or '-' for n in range(9)])

        def formatDate(mtime):
            now = time.gmtime()
            info = {
                'month': _months[mtime.tm_mon],
                'day': mtime.tm_mday,
                'year': mtime.tm_year,
                'hour': mtime.tm_hour,
                'minute': mtime.tm_min
                }
            if now.tm_year != mtime.tm_year:
                return '%(month)s %(day)02d %(year)5d' % info
            else:
                return '%(month)s %(day)02d %(hour)02d:%(minute)02d' % info

        format = ('%(directory)s%(permissions)s%(hardlinks)4d '
                  '%(owner)-9s %(group)-9s %(size)15d %(date)12s '
                  '%(name)s')

        return format % {
            'directory': directory and 'd' or '-',
            'permissions': formatMode(permissions),
            'hardlinks': hardlinks,
            'owner': owner[:8],
            'group': group[:8],
            'size': size,
            'date': formatDate(time.gmtime(modified)),
            'name': name}

    def sendListResponse(self, name, response):
        self.sendLine(self._formatOneListResponse(name, *response))


    # Proxy IConsumer to our transport
    def registerProducer(self, producer, streaming):
        return self.transport.registerProducer(producer, streaming)

    def unregisterProducer(self):
        self.transport.unregisterProducer()
        self.transport.loseConnection()

    def write(self, data):
        if self.isConnected:
            return self.transport.write(data)
        raise Exception("Crap damn crap damn crap damn")


    # Pretend to be a producer, too.
    def _conswrite(self, bytes):
        try:
            self._cons.write(bytes)
        except:
            self._onConnLost.errback()

    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        if self._cons is not None:
            self._conswrite(bytes)
        else:
            self._buffer.append(bytes)

    def _unregConsumer(self, ignored):
        self._cons.unregisterProducer()
        self._cons = None
        del self._onConnLost
        return ignored

    def registerConsumer(self, cons):
        assert self._cons is None
        self._cons = cons
        self._cons.registerProducer(self, True)
        for chunk in self._buffer:
            self._conswrite(chunk)
        self._buffer = None
        if self.isConnected:
            self._onConnLost = d = defer.Deferred()
            d.addBoth(self._unregConsumer)
            return d
        else:
            self._cons.unregisterProducer()
            self._cons = None
            return defer.succeed(None)

    def resumeProducing(self):
        self.transport.resumeProducing()

    def pauseProducing(self):
        self.transport.pauseProducing()

    def stopProducing(self):
        self.transport.stopProducing()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing your own DTP you should probably explore implementing `twisted.protocols.ftp.IFTPShell`.  If you do this, Twisted will take care of all of the protocol logic for you, including the DTP, and all you have to do is take responsibility for producing the right file listings and contents.

Take a look at how `twisted.protocols.ftp.FTPAnonymousShell` is implemented to get an idea of what this entails.

Take a look at `twisted.protocols.ftp.BaseFTPRealm` and `doc/core/examples/ftpserver.py` to see how to integrate your `IFTPShell` implementation into a Twisted-based FTP server.

Comment: @ Jean-Paul Calderone: Thanks for your reply, Can you please provide some useful link or any code for how can I use this?

Comment: I checked the following link but not get any idea how to use this with Objective C.
http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-8.2.0/twisted/protocols/ftp.py#L1512

Comment: That link is to the 8.2.0 source code - code from 5 or 6 years ago.  You might want to browse the latest release instead.  Here's the current ftp server example, <https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/ftpserver.py>

Comment: Also, I don't understand the Objective C reference.